# How does Formatfloat work

Tags: delphi, floating-point, format

In this code:

```
FormatFloat('0.##########',XX.AsFloat)
```

If the value XX in the database is 12.12345, what value will it return?
The number of # is more than 5 decimal places, so will it do extra rounding?
I can't find a doc for this `FormatFloat`.

I'd also like to know what `.AsFloat` does.

Comment: Why don't you just write a test program?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I run it I get find `FormatFloat('0.###########',12.123456) =  12.123456`. So there are no trailing spaces, and no extra 0s.  You can't extrapolate that one case to a general rule though because there are LOTS of floating point values that can't be represented exactly in binary. So the general answer is you'll get a number with at least one digit to the left of where the decimal would have been, and you'll either get a decimal place and a variable number of decimals on the right side, or no decimal place at all.

There is no reasonable way to predict it other than having an intimate knowledge of IEEE Floating Point encoding, and the limitations of binary floating point numeric storage. Try the above with 1.0 for example, and you get '1' and no decimal places.

AsFloat is a method of an object, and if you want to know how it's implemented, and as you haven't told us what type XX is, we can't tell you that. But you don't need to ask us, you can just Ctrl+Click on it.

Another day, another referral to [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Thanks, Warren. Acutally I have the code FormatFloat('0.###############',XX.AsFloat), XX is get from a procedure and it is a field in database, in database XX 's value is 12.1200000000(10 places of decimals), but after this FormatFloat, it becomes 12.120000000000001(it rounding it to extra 0.000000000000001)

Comment: I call that "ragged floating point format" because the length is variable.

Comment: Rounding is not the only thing going on. Read that link... What Every Computer Scientist Should know...  You are using a computer and using floating point types. You should read it.

Comment: Thanks for this. If I want to do a float to string convention, and I want to keep the decimal as it is in the float and don't want to use a unique format, is this possible? Like a float 23.24 I could get the string '23.24', but for float 23.1234, I could get '23.1234', is there a way to do the AS IS convention?

Comment: Warren, among the "floating point values that can't be represented exactly in binary" is the value you tested, [12.123456](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=12.123456). Compare with [12.12](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=12.12).

Comment: While the Value parameter of FormatFloat is declared as Extended and # standing for a optional digit place holder, the result ís predictable as long as the input for Value is a variable of Extended type or is a hardcoded floating point value with a maximum of 19-20 significant digits. In those cases there should be no rounding. But as .AsFloat is typically declared as Double, the result indeed is not predictable.

Comment: Hi NGLN, so is there a way I can convert this as Float other than Double?

Comment: @Warren: +1 for link (and answer). @spspli: What database are you using? What is the exact datatype of the column you're reading using .AsFloat? What is the field type (TFloatField, TStringField, etc.) that Delphi is creating for the column?